# boto not picking up ~/.aws/config in ansible amazon.aws.ec2 module

Tags: ansible, boto, ansible-2.x

I need to **assume** a role from ec2 (another role) (first account) and then launch instances in the assumed role account. (2nd account)

My **~/.aws/config** file:

```
[default]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123:role/assume_role
credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata
```

I used the **amazon.aws.ec2** module to launch instances. The module uses the older boto version.

It looks like boto is not picking up aws config file and launches from the ec2's role account.

Any ideas or workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

**instance_profile_name: string**

```
instance_role: "{{ iam_role }}"
```

Name of the IAM instance profile (i.e. what the EC2 console refers to as an "IAM Role") to use. Boto library must be 2.5.0+.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_module.html

Comment: It assumes the role in another account as well? (If i have the privileges obviously).

Comment: A role has an ARN resource. It doesn't matter in which account it is as long as the correct permissions are set. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Comment: I specified it like

**instance_profile_name: arn:aws:iam::123:role/assume_role**

and it didnt seem to work. Profile not found it says.

Comment: One key piece is that "profile" is passed directly to the boto3 library, if you don't use "local", then you'll need to make sure that the profile is available wherever the module is actually being executed

Comment: Yesss! The issue here is this module uses boto, not boto3. All other modules like ec2_group or ec2_key uses boto3. So it picks up the config file by default. Only this module doesnt!